# Cannot use DOM to manipulate Onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My intention is to manipulate 'onclick' attribute in HTML tag by DOM but it always messages me

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
> at hopeNoError (js.html:102)
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (js.html:32)

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('run')
hopeNoError = function() {
  getUrl = document.getElementById('url');
  getDmn = document.getElementById('domain');
  pushUrl = document.getElementById('aBtn').setAttribute('onclick', getUrl);
  pushDmn = document.getElementById('aBtn').setAttribute('textcontent', getDmn);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="card text-white bg-dark">
      <div class="card-header"><code class="CodeInLine">&lt;a&gt;</code></div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">This is called "Anchor Tag"</h5>
        <p class="card-text"><strong>You know what? </strong></p>
        <p>You can change the URL and the display text</p>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6"> Try it here
            <p>1.Put the URL here</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="anchor" placeholder="http://www.google.com" id="url"></p>
            <p>2.Put a display name here</p>
            <p><input type="text" name="domain_name" placeholder="Google Search" id="domain"></p>
            <p>3.Click this button here</p>
            <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" id="run" onclick="hopeNoError()">RUN</button></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 text-center"> Your result (Click it,)
            <p class="outcome mt-5">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" id="aBtn" onclick="http://www.google.com">Google</button>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You haven't included the dots in the ids of the elements. Just remove the dots from `gEBI`s.

Comment: For future reference. Whenever you use `getElementById`, `querySelector`, .etc, and you get an error saying `cannot ... property ... of null`, then it means that the element you are looking for has not been found. This can be multiple reasons, but in your case you are using `getElementById` wrong by using a *class selector* (dot) inside the strings, which makes the DOM look for the element with the id `.run`, which doesn't exist. But `run` does.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I have added .(dot) to every of my class id but after I tested by clicking 'RUN' button. the console didn't work or sent any message. What should I do?

Comment: It's better to remove the dot from every `id` attribute and `getElementById` call. You'll be making your life easier. If the console didn't show a message, then it means that your script either ran just fine or didn't run at all. But it would help a lot if you could edit your question to tell us what you're trying to accomplish. The code doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I have edited. please check

Comment: Thanks for adding the HTML, but it's still unclear what you're trying to do here. Please *explain* your project and exactly what doesn't work. Be detailed.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I simply just wanted to create a teaching project on how to use HTML tags. And this is the first tag I started.

Here is what I have planned on my head
1.Create 2 input boxes to collect URL and Textcontent
2.Make a button that can put those 2 boxes' value into another button's attributes which are URL and Textcontent 
3.Make another button to store URL and Textcontent

Answer (score 0):

onclick is for invoking a javascript function, not going directly to a URL. But what you want can be accomplished by using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), like so:

```js
const runBtn = document.getElementById('run');
const aBtn = document.getElementById('aBtn');

const changeButtonBehaviour = () => {
    const url = document.getElementById('url').value;
    const domain = document.getElementById('domain').value;
    aBtn.innerText = domain;
    aBtn.dataset.url = url;
};

const goTo = (ev) => {
    // maybe you'd want to use location.href here
    const url = ev.target.dataset.url;
    console.log(`imagine us being directed to ${url}`);
};

runBtn.addEventListener('click', changeButtonBehaviour);
aBtn.addEventListener('click', goTo);
```

```html
<p><input type="text" name="anchor" placeholder="http://www.google.com" id="url"></p>
<p><input type="text" name="domain_name" placeholder="Google Search" id="domain"></p>

<button type="button" class="btn" id="run">RUN</button></p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" id="aBtn" data-url="http://www.google.com">Google</button>
```